# Core data replace relationships on merge

Tags: core-data, merge, one-to-many

I have an scenario on which I am merging an object with a to-many relationship. My privacy policy is `mergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType` and I have also tried `overwriteMergePolicyType`. When the object gets merged, instead of taking the value of the relationships of the object in-memory and replacing the previous values, it just adds them to the set.

So far, I've managed to do some manual house-keeping to delete the old objects but this is far from ideal. Is there any way I can replace the set in disk exactly with the the set in memory and not have to clean it manually?

Comment: A relationship consists of two sides. Maybe such a merge you describe would invalidate the other part of said relationship? I‘m not sure. You can try to destroy the relationship from both sides before the merge(before saving!?), maybe then the merge works correctly?

Comment: I thought about that but I was under the impression that once you break the relationship from one side, it break it from both sides because the relationship has an inverse. What you're suggesting the same amount of extra manual work I'm currently doing. I find it unnatural to that `object.oneToManyRelationship = Set(relationshipObjects)` does not replace the previous set and instead adds to it.